# Not Triggering event handler of UIButton from a Method

Tags: ios, uibutton

I just need to trigger a UIButton programmatically . I have seen many of posts such as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625651/programmatically-fire-button-click-event`

> [btnLocations sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

This statement working fine in the " viewDidLoad " and also in another button handler.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[btnName2 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

&&&&&&&

- (IBAction)btnName1:(id)sender {
[btnName2 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}
```

This works fine . but why it is not triggering from **user defined method**.
Like this :

```
-(void) myMEthod
{
  if(true)
{
 [btnName2 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}
}
```

Simple one . But I didn't get the reason

I just need to know why it is not happening ?? And any alternative to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: is the user defined method called from the main thread?  If not, you'll need to do a performSelectorOnMainThread since UI events must be run on the main thread.

Comment: @MikeM : How to call from mainThread. basically It has happening from MainThread only but I'm not sure\.

Comment: Wether it is entering if(true){} block??

Comment: Yes , That is working fine .

Comment: I'm achieving the functionalities of "myMethod" except this statement.

Comment: ok, I've added an answer that shows how to invoke a call on the main thread.  Not sure that's the issue, but maybe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be an issue trying to invoke a UI event on another thread.  Try adding this:

```
    - (void)fireButtonEvent:(id)unused
    {
            [btnName2 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }
```

and then call using

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fireButtonEvent:)
          withObject:nil
          waitUntilDone:false];
```

Comment: Works fine . Thanks but Not included all functionalities . Here adding

Comment: Its triggering for some Logs , Actually I'm adding subView to the View . but It is not happening from this way . Happening perfectly from UI Click