# How programmatically click facebook loginView in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, triggers

I am trying to add a FBLoginView in my app like described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/).

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

I actually intend to hide it by setting

```
loginView.hidden = YES;
```

Then i want to trigger a click on `loginView` when some other event happens, something similar to this post said

[Programmatically fire button click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625651/programmatically-fire-button-click-event)

But the FBLoginView does not receive a button click message. Is there still away to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look into FBLoginView sources you'll see that FBLoginView is a subclass of UIView with UIButton added as a subview. There's no defined public property to that button, so it's not accessible in a normal way.

The way to do it is to iterate over subviews as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281054/317928. But it's a bad practice, because view hierarchy may change in future.

Also see [Facebook login tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/), section Login with API calls. This section describes how to use simple button for authentication.

Comment: Yes, finding the embedded button and sending click event to it indeed works.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code snippet that works for me.

```
for (id obj in loginView.subviews) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton * loginButton =  obj;
        [loginButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        break;
    }
}
```

It will trigger Facebook login programmatically and can also be used to trigger logout. There is however an ugly effect for logout. This pop will show

[image]

at the bottom of screen. I hope there is a way to hide it too.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, much more elegant way to trigger Facebook login programmatically, is by managing session for example:

```
-(void)loginLogout
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended)
    {

        // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
        // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    }
    else
    {
    // Initialize a session object
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"publish_actions", @"user_photos"]];

    // Set the active session
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    // Open the session
    [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                FBSessionState status,
                                NSError *error) {

                if(error == nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"login successful");
                    // Respond to session state changes,
                    // ex: updating the view
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"login unsuccessful");
                }

            }];
    }
}
```

Moreover, changing session state will by noticed by hidden LoginView, and its delegate methods like

> loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView

will be triggered (without mentioned earlier ugly pop).

Comment: I succeeded in getting "login successful" message, but loginViewShowingLoggedInUser delegate method is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

**FBLoginView** has two subviews, you can check in with subview of the view is the button located and then you can active the Action using the next code:

```
[loginView.subviews[0] sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can trigger facebook with the following code:

```
for (id subview in self.facebookLoginView.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *loginButton =  subview;
        [loginButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        break;
    }
}
```

and for google plus (if smbdy is interested):

```
[self.googleLoginView sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

BE AWARE: if the SDK changes you have to retest it and modify it maybe!